# Implementing Mean Reversion

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a [mean reversion](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/meanreversion.asp#:%7E:text=Mean%20reversion%20is%20a%20financial,long%2Dterm%20average%20over%20time.) trading algorithm.

`data` is list containing candlestick objects. The `c`-property is the closing price of that candlestick.

I have the following Python code:

```
# Calculate average price of datapoint.
def avg_price(dp):
    return (dp.h + dp.l + dp.c) / 3

# Calculate the mean.
def mean(datapoints):
    _avg_price = sum(avg_price(dp) for dp in datapoints)
    return _avg_price / len(datapoints)

# Get array of deviations for each datapoint.
def deviations(datapoints, mean):
    return [avg_price(dp) - mean for dp in datapoints]

# Get the z_score.
def zscore(datapoints):
    
    _mean = mean(datapoints[:-1])
    sqrd_deviations = [d ** 2 for d in deviations(datapoints[:-1], _mean)]
    variance = sum(sqrd_deviations[:-1]) / (len(datapoints) - 1)
    std_deviation = math.sqrt(variance)

    z_score = (avg_price(datapoints[-1]) - _mean) / std_deviation
    return z_score

def func(data):

    window = 25

    if len(data) <= 25:
        return 0

    z_score = zscore(data)

    if z_score > 0.1:
        return 0.0005   # buy
    if z_score < -0.1:
        return -0.0002

    return 0
```

I basically have simple functions like `avg_price()`, `mean()` and `deviations()` to calculate what their names indicate.

Then I have a function `zscore()`. This function calculates the standard deviation by taking all the datapoints in the calculation. Then I calculate the deviation of the last price point and divide that by the standard deviation. This is the z_score. This function for example returns a z-score of 0.06631069256231889.

Finally I check the z-score the compare how much the deviation of the last price point deviates from the standard variation. If it exceeds a specific threshold a buy/sell signal is returned.

Is this the correct way to implement mean reversion?